# Interface Builder on iOS: how to share UITabBarController in universal app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

If I'm creating a universal iPhone/iPad app, I have two XIBs. One main XIB for each device type.
The iPad version is supposed to get a `UISplitViewController` as the root controller, the iPhone a `UITabBarController`.

However, the `UITabBarController` used on the iPhone is exactly the one I would like to use in the iPad's `UISplitViewController` as the master controller.

What is the best/cleanest way to achieve it without duplicating the `UITabBarController`?
Do I add a third XIB that contains nothing but the `UITabBarController` and then add it programmatically? Or is there a more elegant way using Interface Builder's abilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I add a third XIB that contains nothing but the `UITabBarController` and then add it programmatically?

Yes, that's what I'd do. There's no Interface Builder support for something like this.

Comment: I have tried your idea meanwhile. I add a XIB that contains the controller I want to share. I make the file's owner my app delegate. Then I add an outlet to the controller. The problem is: the outlet is always NIL. Could it be that I have to manually load the XIB before getting access to its contents?

Comment: @jtbandes - would you be willing to share the code/syntax for this? Because all my experimentation in trying to load the UITabBarController from a XIB (that contains nothing else) has yielded no results at all. [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:thirdXibFileName bundle:nil] doens't do the trick. Also could you clarify if you answered the question based on something that you *think* should be possible or have your ever had a chance to do it and see it working?

Comment: @pulkitsinghal: I think doing that won't work unless you manually add views for the tab bar controller etc. I think what Krumelur was asking about was an empty xib where you drag in a UITabBarController (this will come with a view). Or you could just create it programmatically. The point is that based on the device ("interface idiom") you want to do different things with it (set as the root view controller, or add to a split view controller). My answer was based on what sounded like the best method; not that I've done it, but there's no reason it shouldn't work that way.